# Can I add/remove the class of an li using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I'm having trouble recreating something I saw on another website.

I need to have an 'active' class on the LI selected

I'm using Umbraco CMS but not all the CSS loads right away for some reason, I also can't get the Javascript function to work.

I've exacerbated my knowledge of HTML and CSS at this point.

```
$( '.nav-tabs a' ).on( 'click', function () {
    $( '.nav-tabs a' ).find( 'li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
    $( this ).parent( 'li' ).addClass( 'active' );
});


.schedule-tabs {
    display: block;
    max-width: 650px;
}

.nav-tabs a {
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 52px;
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s ease; 
}

.nav-tabs .active li a {
    background: #004964;
}

.nav-tabs a:active, .nav-tabs a:focus {
    background: #004964;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.tab-content {
    padding: 30px;
    max-width: 650px;
    background: #fff;
}

.label .label-secondary span {
    float: right;
    background: #da4444;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12pt;
    padding: 3px;
}


<div class="tabs schedule-tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#oct8" data-toggle="tab">Oct 8th</a></li>
<li><a href="#oct9" data-toggle="tab">Oct 9th</a></li>
<li><a href="#oct10" data-toggle="tab">Oct 10th</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content lgray-bg">
<div id="oct8" class="tab-pane active">
<div class="view view-conf-schedule view-id-conf_schedule view-display-id-block view-dom-id-c1b8d1fcc9e989a989c4f0a222dc6ae6">
<div class="view-content">
<div class="event-task">
<h5>Pre-Conference Reception &amp; Registration<span class="label label-secondary">6:00 pm</span></h5>
<div class="view view-speakers view-id-speakers view-display-id-block_2 view-dom-id-932d21aad7d0d6a8bf1e41ac95ab0f1c"></div>
<p>Location: Hotel Halifax (Bluenose Room)</p>
<p>Networking, cash bar, refreshments and light snacks provided</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="oct9" class="tab-pane">
<div class="view view-conf-schedule view-id-conf_schedule view-display-id-block view-dom-id-9e8eaa7629f84acd7c096522dfe6590f">
<div class="view-content">
<div class="event-task">
<h5>Conference Sessions Day 1<span class="label label-secondary">9:00 am</span></h5>
<div class="view view-speakers view-id-speakers view-display-id-block_2 view-dom-id-afede0c1055f0e4a61ec88750c265e44"></div>
<p>Conference sessions to be announced.</p>
</div>
<div class="event-task">
<h5>Offsite Social Event<span class="label label-secondary">7:00 pm</span></h5>
<div class="view view-speakers view-id-speakers view-display-id-block_2 view-dom-id-1957e7851f79b2c1a727a3f299bde2b9"></div>
<p>Location: To be announced</p>
<p>Networking, cash bar, appetizers provided</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="oct10" class="tab-pane">
<div class="view view-conf-schedule view-id-conf_schedule view-display-id-block view-dom-id-4d5a54b54db033c3269c3ed762cdc807">
<div class="view-content">
<div class="event-task">
<h5>Conference Sessions Day 2<span class="label label-secondary">9:00 am</span></h5>
<div class="view view-speakers view-id-speakers view-display-id-block_2 view-dom-id-0ad3697843cc6abfa6e8485c0195cded"></div>
<p>Conference sessions to be announced.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The first tab should already be in an 'Active' state and have a blue background, and should switch when the other buttons are selected. I can't get it to replicate in codepen either.

Working example here: https://globalpetroleumshow.com/test

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is important remove active class en whole way. Remove active from all li. But add active class for current li by id.

```
$(".nav-tabs > li").click(function(){
$('.nav-tabs > li').removeClass('active'); // Remove classs all
$('.nav-tabs >li#li_'+this.id.substr(3)).addClass('active'); // add class in current li
});

<div class="tabs schedule-tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<!-- add id at each li item-->
<li class="active" id="li_oct8"><a href="#oct8" data-toggle="tab">Oct 8th</a></li>
<li id="li_oct9"><a href="#oct9" data-toggle="tab">Oct 9th</a></li>
<li id="li_oct10"><a href="#oct10" data-toggle="tab">Oct 10th</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include the active class to the content to hide and show based on what anchor tag is clicked. You can find the id of the appropriate tab panel by getting the href attribute of the anchor tag that is clicked.

```js
$('.nav-tabs a').on('click', function() {

  $('.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.tab-pane.active').removeClass('active');

  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
  $($(this).attr("href")).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.schedule-tabs {
  display: block;
  max-width: 650px;
}

.nav-tabs a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 52px;
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.nav-tabs .active a {
  background: #004964;
}

.tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-pane.active {
  display: block;
}

.nav-tabs a:active,
.nav-tabs a:focus {
  background: #004964;
}

.nav-tabs>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.tab-content {
  padding: 30px;
  max-width: 650px;
  background: #fff;
}

.label .label-secondary span {
  float: right;
  background: #da4444;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs schedule-tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#oct8" data-toggle="tab">Oct 8th</a></li>
    <li><a href="#oct9" data-toggle="tab">Oct 9th</a></li>
    <li><a href="#oct10" data-toggle="tab">Oct 10th</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content lgray-bg">
  <div id="oct8" class="tab-pane active">
    <div class="view view-conf-schedule view-id-conf_schedule view-display-id-block view-dom-id-c1b8d1fcc9e989a989c4f0a222dc6ae6">
      <div class="view-content">
        <div class="event-task">
          <h5>Pre-Conference Reception &amp; Registration<span class="label label-secondary">6:00 pm</span></h5>
          <div class="view view-speakers view-id-speakers view-display-id-block_2 view-dom-id-932d21aad7d0d6a8bf1e41ac95ab0f1c"></div>
          <p>Location: Hotel Halifax (Bluenose Room)</p>
          <p>Networking, cash bar, refreshments and light snacks provided</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="oct9" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="view view-conf-schedule view-id-conf_schedule view-display-id-block view-dom-id-9e8eaa7629f84acd7c096522dfe6590f">
      <div class="view-content">
        <div class="event-task">
          <h5>Conference Sessions Day 1<span class="label label-secondary">9:00 am</span></h5>
          <div class="view view-speakers view-id-speakers view-display-id-block_2 view-dom-id-afede0c1055f0e4a61ec88750c265e44"></div>
          <p>Conference sessions to be announced.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="event-task">
          <h5>Offsite Social Event<span class="label label-secondary">7:00 pm</span></h5>
          <div class="view view-speakers view-id-speakers view-display-id-block_2 view-dom-id-1957e7851f79b2c1a727a3f299bde2b9"></div>
          <p>Location: To be announced</p>
          <p>Networking, cash bar, appetizers provided</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="oct10" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="view view-conf-schedule view-id-conf_schedule view-display-id-block view-dom-id-4d5a54b54db033c3269c3ed762cdc807">
      <div class="view-content">
        <div class="event-task">
          <h5>Conference Sessions Day 2<span class="label label-secondary">9:00 am</span></h5>
          <div class="view view-speakers view-id-speakers view-display-id-block_2 view-dom-id-0ad3697843cc6abfa6e8485c0195cded"></div>
          <p>Conference sessions to be announced.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I tried your code but it still isn't working for some reason.. I've reached out to the developers to ask why

Comment: I ended up getting it working!! I'm having a bit of trouble with this little CSS arrow div I created as well though.. removing the class was relatively easy but I can't figure out how to apply it again to the new div that's clicked. I'm using $(this).parent('div').addClass('active'); but I don't know how to target the right div

Comment: What is the HTML code for the arrow? And where did you put the arrow element in the HTML?

Comment: <div class="tabs schedule-tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Oct 8th</a>
<div class="arrow-down active"></div>
</li>
<li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Oct 9th</a>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
</li>
<li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Oct 10th</a>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: Ok so, the div is right after the anchor tag, or in other words, the div and the anchor tag are siblings. So you can use $(this).siblings('.arrow-down').addClass('active'); You might find this link useful too: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/

Answer (score -1):

`$( '.nav-tabs a' ).find( 'li.active' )` is looking for `<li>` that are  *descendants* of `<a>`

Try

```
$('.nav-tabs li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
```

Comment: Gave it a shot but I'm not entirely sure my JS is even working at all, although it's saved in the right place..

Comment: Any errros in browser dev tools console? Is code wrapped in document.ready?

Comment: No errors, just wrapped it in document.ready but still no changes

Comment: Did you include a script tag to the jQuery source?

Comment: I believe it's already integrated into the head of the site, it won't let me add any scripts into the HTML block unfortunately